# DST lost in datetime strptime with pytz Python

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, strptime

I have a string format

```
frmt = "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
```

When I convert now() to this format & back, I lose DST.

```
print datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime(frmt), frmt).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")).dst()


print datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")).dst()
```

The first print returns 1:00:00 the second print returns 0:00:00.
Is there a way to keep DST when using datetime.strptime?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you are working with strings at all here, since your example is just showing "now".  If that is indeed a requirement, then please show starting with a specific string and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @MattJohnson The data comes in from an API as a string. I was using `now` to explain the issue. An example string would be "06-27-2014 07:53:01 PM". The tz is determined by a config setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

> This library differs from the documented Python API for tzinfo implementations; if you want to create local wallclock times you need to use the `localize()` method documented in this document. ...

You should also consider starting with "now" according to UTC, rather than according to your own computer's time zone.  Then you can *convert* to the time zone you have in mind.

Also, you should use `"America/New_York"` instead of `"US/Eastern"` as the latter is in the tzdb for backwards compatibility purposes only.  It will work, but it's not preferred.

```
utc_dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
eastern_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
```

Comment: And the reason is because when you use `replace` the `tzinfo` object doesn't have a chance to adjust itself, and even if it did it doesn't have access to the date. This is a flaw in the `datetime` API.

Comment: @MarkRansom: btw, `pytz.utc` is a special timezone (always the same UTC offset) that can be used with `.replace()`: `utc_dt = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` i.e., `.localize()` is not necessary for UTC. Though I prefer: `utc_dt = datetime.now(pytz.utc)` spelling (it works for any timezone).